# REST API with Accept Header application/json returns a number

Tags: json, rest, http

Novice Question:

I have a rest api in my application : `https://hostname/app-rest/session/manager/active-session/count`. The API returns the number of sessions with certain attributes like connection type, status, etc.

When I set the request header `Content-Type: application/json`, response header `Accept: application/json` and send a request with body like:
`{"loggedIn": "yes", connectionType" : "mobile"}`, I get a response with a number 0, 1, 2 etc.

QUESTION: Based on this: http://json.org/, it seems that the response is a valid JSON format. However, is this good design practice?  Isn't it preferable to return the value in a key value pair format so that all clients can understand and parse the response - instead of assuming that the client has the knowledge of what is returned by the API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [original RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), a number on its own is ***not*** a valid JSON text. JSON must always begin with `{` or `[` (optionally preceded by some whitespace characters).

There is a [new RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) that revises this by allowing any JSON value to be an entire JSON text. If you go by this RFC, then a number on its own is calid JSON.

For the time being I would recommend returning an object, with a key describing the meaning of the number returned, since that will conform to both RFCs.